# Elasticsearch filtered query not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get a very basic filtered query to work with Elasticsearch. I have a logstash index which has multiple entries for network traffic logs. I am trying to filter based on the HTTP request type - GET. Here is what I filtered query looks like ...

```
curl -XGET "http://<myhost>:9200/<myindex>/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}     
            },
          "filter": {
              "term": {"verb":"GET"}
            }
        }
      }
  }
}'
```

This seems to be matching in syntax with the documentation here,
http://www.elasticsearch.com/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_combining_queries_with_filters.html

But I get 0 hits. The same query with an exact match syntax works. I have thousands of such messages where "verb":"GET"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `verb` field has been indexed using the default analyzer, then most probably it ended up being indexed as a lower case: "get" instead of "GET", "delete" instead of "DELETE".

`term` filtering just gets the filtered value, `GET` in your query and it doesn't analyze it (this is how it works). So, basically, you are looking for value `GET` in a list of documents containing `get`, `delete`, `post` etc.

These being said, you actually need to look for the lowercased value:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}     
            },
          "filter": {
              "term": {"verb":"get"}
            }
        } } } }
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. Yes, that was it. It is strange ... but as you said it is how it works. sigh !!

Comment: It is not strange, this is the difference between analysing or not and using a match query of a term. It might not be what you expect, but I do not think it is strange.

Comment: ES's default analyzer actually breaks it into tokens that are all lowercase: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html